Multiple repetitive tables
I'm querying results out of 2 tables, at a time, which has a repetitive pattern.
select 
    abc, xyz
from
    2010_Q1_result 
inner join 
    2010_Q1_run

(next comes 2010_Q2... inner join 2010_Q2_run all the way to 2024_Q1_result inner join 2024_Q1_run).
So far I have been changing the year and quarter manually in the query and pulling out results one by one.
How do I automate it to a single query?

Please tag the DBMS you’re using, as answers can vary materially between each.

You fix your design; you shouldn't have a new table per quarter, you should have 1 table with a column for the year and quarter ( or perhaps just the date).

I wish I could. I'm not an architect or developer. This is the way it was given to us from the vendor for years now.

Have you researched the concept of a dynamic query?  One where you construct the query via string math and execute via Exec().  see https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/

That it is given to you in that format doesn't mean you shouldn't change it afterwards. I assume this isn't their database design? If it is, it's time to change vendor, that's a fundamentally terrible design decision.

You could consider pulling once with a UNION:
select 2010 as year, 'q1' as quarter, abc, xyz
from
2010_Q1_result 
inner join 2010_Q1_run
UNION ALL
select 2010 , 'q2' , abc, xyz
from
2010_Q2_result 
inner join 2010_Q2_run
UNION ALL
select 2010 , 'q3', abc, xyz
from
2010_Q3_result 
inner join 2010_Q3_run
UNION ALL
....

Once written that will spit out every record with columns denoting the year and column. You could toss that whole nasty thing in a view and then just SELECT * FROM my_view_that_I_made so you don't have to write this every time you want to query.

What happens when we need records next year from 2025? Will the view need to be edited? How far into the future can we reasonably prepare for?

this is a one time thing , with the vendor going away end of this year.

With a data structure like that, good riddance ;)  If this was a long-term thing, then a possible next step would be to write a procedure (our using python or what-have-you) to query metadata to grab the tablenames in scope to then construct and execute this SQL on the fly.
